# Typeorm specify data length of simple-json column in MySql

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I'm using typeorm in my application and I have a simple-json column in my models that can get quite large in some scenarios. In the MySql DB I want this set to `LONGTEXT` however once doing so all migrations try to revert this back to `TEXT` and try dropping the column. Is there a way to use the simple-json column type as a longtext in my MySql DB?

Example Migration generation

up:

```
await queryRunner.query("ALTER TABLE `results` DROP COLUMN `rawData`", undefined);
await queryRunner.query("ALTER TABLE `results` ADD `rawData` text NULL", undefined);
```

down:

```
await queryRunner.query("ALTER TABLE `results` DROP COLUMN `rawData`", undefined);
await queryRunner.query("ALTER TABLE `results` ADD `rawData` longtext NULL", undefined);
```

Comment: Can we take a look at your entity definition?

Comment: Yes this is the column definition for the entity in question

@Column('simple-json')
@ValidateNested()
@IsNotEmpty()
@Type(() => OutputMap)
public rawData!: OutputMap